# eloquen and php active record cant find table because additional table suffix 's'

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent, phpactiverecord

i just get [php active record](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/index/main) or [eloquen](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquen) from laravel
running on codeigniter. first attempt create model it's run well, but after that i got this following error:

> Type: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table  dog.ids' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `ids`)

so for get it running i need to change every table in database with addition suffix 's' but keep model name without suffix 's'.

for example:
for model id

```
class id extends ActiveRecords/Model{
}
```

need tabe ids.
so how to keep table have the same name with model?
i don't understand what really happened. both library uses pdo for bridging data.

---

ps : sorry for my really bad english

Answer (score 1):

There are certain conventions in phpactiverecord, like the whole plural thing you refer to. Luckily you can override them. This way you don't need to change your database.

```
class id extends ActiveRecords/Model{
    static $table_name = 'id';
}
```

see: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/3/wiki/Conventions

Comment: and for eloquent's table `protected $table = 'id';`.  looks ugly. but what should i do...? this is the only solution. i don't accepted yet, but +1 for solution. thanks...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you should do. For phpactiverecord I would advice to try to keep to their conventions. Name your tables, fields etc so that phpactiverecord understands it. Also, keep everyting lowercase etc etc. I cannot see how much trouble that will be for you though.

Comment: Conventional over configuration